# Remove-AppxPackage noisy in the console

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am working on automating `Remove-AppxPackage` and it works fine, but even when using

```
Remove-AppxPackage $appXPackage -allUsers:$allUsers -errorAction:stop > $null
```

I am seeing some junk in the console. Something of a progress indicator, with a sequence of `o`'s one screen, but it doesn't remain after processing. It's just ugly during processing. Is there some way to make it quiet, or am I stuck with ugly?

EDIT: I revised the code for the verbose argument, thus:

```
Remove-AppxPackage $appXPackage -allUsers:$allUsers -verbose:$false -errorAction:stop > $null
```

and I am still getting processing artifacts on screen, as you see here.
[image]

Comment: got a screenshot?

Comment: @4c74356b41, yes, added a screenshot. In use that last line will fill up with o's until completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove the progress indication during the execution of the commands you can use this:

```
$progressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

place this before the code that is displaying progress bar.

Comment: This does not seem to work in PowerShell 7.4.1. I still see "Deployment operation progress..." in yellow text.

Comment: it might not, the answer is 5 years old. feel free to update the answer

Answer (score 0):

it should be `| Out-Null` at the end and if you don't want to see the verbose output use `-verbose:$false`

Comment: I tried the verbose flag, and no go, as y=shown in the revised OP. As for Out-Null, my understanding is > $null is the same functionality, but more efficient. I found a page somewhere that compares three different ways to pipe to oblivion and > $null won by a landslide. For thoroughness I did test with | Out-Null, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Before you run your `remove-appxpackage` command set this value `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`. Note I didn't tested it.

Comment: yeah, `out-null` and `> $null` achieve the same result. performance difference is negligible. $progresspreference is what you need probably

Comment: @4c74356b41 - That was the ticket! Wanna make it an answer so I can accept and upvote that bad boy!